# how to get rid of this message in cygwin startup?

Tags: cygwin

I just reinstalled cygwin because I wanted to install Git. But after installation, every time I start cygwin I get this message:

```
bash: cd: /home/bob: No such file or directory

yao@NY-2B7HVL1 /
$
```

Before the reinstallation, I just get the "yao@etc /". WHO IS THIS BOB???

Comment: Take a look at your `/etc/passwd` file. Is there an entry for an account named `"bob"`?

Comment: @KeithThompson nope, just my name..

Answer (score 0):

Look at your ~/.bashrc file.  Perhaps it references /home/bob, or calls a script that does.  You can track it down by emptying this file out then adding back chunks a bit at a time.